# White Screen for posts on joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla3.5

I've updated my CMS-System to current php8.
After that i get an white screen error if i want to show my posts.
link to the homepage is : https://www.lan-maniac.com/
link sample post: https://www.lan-maniac.com/news/lanmaniac/mit-anleitung-sichtlich-zum-erfolg

Dont know why i get an white screen.
No information in debug modus.

Comment: Please look into your error log on the server. It will tell you the "real" error.

Comment: Please increase the error reporting level in the Joomla Global Configuration. This will reveal the issue. If you check the source code of your "white page" you'll see that it actually not empty. It looks like the code for getting the site name causes the fatal error.

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Its not possible t o detect the error with a higher error level in joomla i said.

but its right. You can proof the apache php logfiles.

and this tell me an old plugin. I deactivated this pluging and white screen is away.